# Ember select making model dirty on init

Tags: ember.js

Having this select in my template makes my model dirty and triggers observer on init, why? I wanna be able to update my model on change but now my update function is triggered on init and i don't wanna make a api call on every single item on init.

template:

```
{{#each booking in bookings itemController="booking"}}
  {{isDirty}} // this is true
  {{view "select" content=dateRange value=booking.playingOn optionValuePath="content.date" optionLabelPath="content.day"}}
{{/each}}
```

controller:

```
  // this is running on init and when you select something in the select drop down.
  updatePlayingOn: function(){
    console.log(this.get('currentState.stateName')); // logs root.loaded.updated.uncommitted 
  }.observes('playingOn')
```

As i have understood value=booking.playingOn updates the playingOn model attribute to the same value and making the model dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Ember select can't handle javascript objects, in this case a Date object. Making my objects to strings solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Had an issue where the selects backing model was using DS.attr('number'), changing to string solved it for me.